# Eclipse looses shortcuts after changing appereance or code formatter

Tags: php, eclipse

I would like to set a customized code formatter and change the appereance in Eclipse PHP 2019-06. 
After making these changes, I set up a new project and added some existing files. In the first moment all shortcuts works fine, but when I restart Eclipse, the shortcuts seem to be changed inside the project. E.g. Ctrl + D for deleting a line or Ctrl + I for formatting selected line do not work anymore even if they appear in the active key bindings from the help menu.

[image: key bindings]

[image: key bindings from preferences]

I also tried to use the shortcut in a project-unbinded file (opened by drag and drop): There the shortcuts still work. So it seems to be related with some project settings but I did not find any settings in the project, that could cause the problems.

I expect Eclipse not to change shortcuts in a project, just because I change the appereance or the code formatter. Does somenone know what is causing the change of the shortcut settings?

Comment: Could you please show which key bindings are listed in _Window > Preferences: General > Keys_ when you filter for `ctrl+d`? Maybe another key binding overwrites the _Delete Line_ binding.

Comment: In _Window > Preferences: General > Keys_ please enter `ctrl+d` in the filter field and show us the (filtered) key bindings with their scopes (_When_ column).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suddenly and surprisingly the shortcuts are working now. What I did: I restarted eclipse again and closed and reopened the project, in which the keys were not accepted.